# Entity Framework throws strange 'Invalid object name' error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-4

I'm having problems performing an insert and continually receive the error `Invalid object name 'dbo.atomic.address'`.  As you can see within the atomic database address does exist:

[image]

This is the `CreateAddress` function. I am passing nulls into `addressline3` and `addressline4`. I have wondered if this might be the problem. I have checked the .tt templates and the `Address` object doesn't have these marked as `Nullable` - problem?

```
public static int CreateAddress(string addressline1, string addressline2, string addressline3,
        string addressline4, string postcode, int cityid, int countryid, int clientid,
        string tag, bool active, string notes = null)
    {
        using (var ctx = new atomicEntities())
        {
            var a = new Address
                        {
                            ClientId = clientid,
                            AddressTag = tag,
                            AddressLine1 = addressline1,
                            AddressLine2 = addressline2,
                            AddressLine3 = addressline3,
                            AddressLine4 = addressline4,
                            CityId = cityid,
                            Postcode = postcode,
                            CountryId = countryid,
                            AddressNotes = notes,
                            Active = active,
                            Token = DateTime.UtcNow
                        };
            ctx.Connection.Open();
            ctx.Addresses.AddObject(a);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            return a.AddressId;
        }    
    }
```

Just for reference, this is the error I receive with the stack:

[image]

Also, the data I am inserting is as follows:

[image]

BusinessStreet2 is empty, but I can confirm that even when populated the error still occurs.

Any help or suggestions welcome on how to make this work! :D  I have read that it might be a plural or singular issue, but I can't see where I am going wrong?

**EDIT** Xml from Atomic.edmx:

```
    <EntityContainer Name="atomicModelStoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="address" EntityType="atomicModel.Store.address" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
 </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="address">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="address_id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="address_id" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="client_id" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="address_tag" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" />
          <Property Name="address_line_1" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="255" />
          <Property Name="address_line_2" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="255" />
          <Property Name="address_line_3" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="255" />
          <Property Name="address_line_4" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="255" />
          <Property Name="city" Type="int" />
          <Property Name="postcode" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="12" />
          <Property Name="country" Type="int" />
          <Property Name="address_notes" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="500" />
          <Property Name="active" Type="bit" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="token" Type="datetime" />
        </EntityType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much faffing about, I found the problem.  This turned out to be a trigger on the table for `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. Doh!  The trigger was obviously untested and completely forgotten:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AddressTrigger 
ON [address]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @Address As Int;
SELECT @Address = i.[address_id] FROM inserted i;
UPDATE [dbo].[atomic].[address]
set
    [token] = GETDATE()
where [address_id] = @Address;
GO
```

I vaguely remember setting these up myself now, but had forgotten since.  Please accept my apologies for wasting everyone's time!  I'll never get the next 3 hours of my life back!

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. I had the exact same problem - Changed the table name but somehow forgot to update the triggers. Believe me, I spent way more than 3 hours debugging this and when I gave up and googled your answer was right on. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem in your mapping because if your database name is `Atomic` the correct name of table is `Atomic.dbo.Address`. Also EF should not need to add database name into object name.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought that very thing, but have no idea how to change it? I have looked for any 'hard coded' references and found none...

Comment: I open up the Atomic.edmx in VS2010 and do Update from Database... ?

Comment: If you open the edmx file as XML and search for the database definition of address table what do you see in table name and schema?

Comment: I have added the XML to the question as an edit... :) Thanks for all your help so far.